# How to pass along .d.ts comment on function that returns a class extending React.Component (vscode)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've got a .d.ts file I'm writing for an npm module teselagen-react-components that is a set of functions/react components. Here is a subset of the definition file in question:

```js
import * as React from "react";


/**
 *
 * I'm a comment
 */
declare class GenericSelect extends React.Component<GenericSelectProps, any> { }

export interface GenericSelectProps {
  layout: string;
}

declare function createGenericSelect() {
  return GenericSelect
}
```

In another module I have a file like so:

```js
//./myOtherProject/someFile.js
import { createGenericSelect, GenericSelect } from "teselagen-react-components";
const GenSel = createGenericSelect()
return <GenSel />
return <GenericSelect />
```

The issue I'm seeing is that when I hover  `<GenericSelect />` I am able to see the comment: 
[image: GenericSelect with comment]

But when I hover the  component, I can't see it!
[image: GenSel with no comment]

If instead of this line:

```
/**
 *
 * I'm a comment
 */
declare class GenericSelect extends React.Component<GenericSelectProps, any> { }
```

I had

```
/**
 *
 * I'm a comment
 */
declare function GenericSelect { }
```

Then I do see the comment!

[image: GenSel() with comment]

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this question would be more appropriate as a bug in VScode if you believe its a bug.

I personally don't think this is a bug, mainly because as you said it shows up in GenSel. If I had to take a guess why, I think it's because the reference when a variable is created just doesn't have the tags to show JSDocs on it.

Comment: @SarhadSalam I don't quite understand what you mean when you say "the reference when a variable is created just doesn't have the tags to show JSDocs on it." 
I also don't know why you think it is something with vscode and not typescript itself?